# npm i is not working after upgrading to the latest node and npm

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, ionic3

I have upgraded `node` and `npm`. Now `ionic 3` (`3.9.2`) project (this works fine before the upgrade to node and npm) is not working for `npm i`. But it is working fine for new projects. Could you tell me how to sort out this issue?

> node: 8.11.2
>
> npm: 5.6.0

This is the error when I tried with `npm i`

```
npm WARN deprecated highcharts-more@0.1.2: this package has been deprecated, just import modules from the highcharts folder
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "node_modules\cordova-plugin-badge" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\lokuge\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-14T07_15_19_651Z-debug.log
```

***Additional info:***  Since this is an old project this doesn't have `package-lock.json`. It has only the `package.json`

***package.json***

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "author": "Ionic Framework",
    "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.0",
        "@ionic-native/app-rate": "4.5.3",
        "@ionic-native/call-number": "4.3.3",
        "@ionic-native/camera": "4.3.2",
        "@ionic-native/contacts": "4.3.3",
        "@ionic-native/core": "4.3.3",
        "@ionic-native/facebook": "4.5.3",
        "@ionic-native/file": "4.5.3",
        "@ionic-native/file-opener": "4.5.3",
        "@ionic-native/firebase": "4.5.3",
        "@ionic-native/globalization": "4.5.3",
        "@ionic-native/google-plus": "4.5.3",
        "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.6.0",
        "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "4.5.3",
        "@ionic-native/network": "4.5.3",
        "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "4.4.2",
        "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "4.3.3",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.2",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.3.2",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
        "@types/papaparse": "4.1.33",
        "angular2-text-mask": "8.0.2",
        "angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.6",
        "call-number": "^1.0.1",
        "cordova-android": "^6.3.0",
        "cordova-ios": "4.5.4",
        "cordova-plugin-apprate": "1.3.0",
        "cordova-plugin-badge": "file:node_modules\\cordova-plugin-badge",
        "cordova-plugin-camera": "2.4.1",
        "cordova-plugin-compat": "1.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-contacts": "2.3.1",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "1.1.7",
        "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "2.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "1.9.1",
        "cordova-plugin-file": "4.3.3",
        "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "2.0.19",
        "cordova-plugin-firebase": "0.1.25",
        "cordova-plugin-globalization": "1.0.9",
        "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "5.2.1",
        "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "1.7.2",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "1.1.16",
        "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "0.9.0-beta.2",
        "cordova-plugin-network-information": "2.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "2.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "4.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.3.0",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.3",
        "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "5.2.1",
        "cordova-sqlite-storage": "2.1.2",
        "es6-promise-plugin": "4.1.0",
        "firebase": "4.8.2",
        "highcharts": "6.0.2",
        "highcharts-more": "0.1.2",
        "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
        "ionic-img-viewer": "2.7.3",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "2.2.1",
        "ionic2-rating": "1.2.2",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "lodash": "4.17.5",
        "moment": "2.19.3",
        "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": "0.0.2",
        "ng2-truncate": "1.3.11",
        "papaparse": "4.3.7",
        "rxjs": "5.5.2",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "text-mask-addons": "3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.18"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.8",
        "typescript": "2.4.2"
    },
    "description": "An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
            "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
            "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
            "cordova-plugin-camera": {
                "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " ",
                "PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
            },
            "cordova-plugin-contacts": {
                "CONTACTS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
            },
            "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {},
            "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": {},
            "call-number": {},
            "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {},
            "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
            "cordova-plugin-firebase": {},
            "cordova-plugin-apprate": {},
            "cordova-plugin-file": {},
            "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": {},
            "cordova-plugin-local-notification": {},
            "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
                "APP_ID": "247328495802670",
                "APP_NAME": "Budget My Reno"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
                "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "com.googleusercontent.apps.593814858306-cd06l64ddacucewsde34aqw22nb"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-globalization": {},
            "cordova-plugin-compat": {},
            "cordova-plugin-network-information": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "android",
            "ios"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange declaration `cordova-plugin-badge": "file:node_modules\\cordova-plugin-badge` in package.json. Try to install this package directly from npm.

Comment: I have removed it manually. Now some of packages were installed. But now it shows this error `error sha1-fh+W2FiKGdIhi7Tbyg1cRC8eJlE= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-fh+W2FiKGdIhi7Tbyg1cRC8eJlE= but got sha1-SeIudoFC4KFoBqxwCtpFWy+nPBQ=. (10643901 bytes)
17794 verbose exit [ 1, true ]`. Any idea? @alexmac

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean && npm i`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it is working. Please put your answer. @alexmac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Replace `cordova-plugin-badge": "file:node_modules\\cordova-plugin-badge` declaration in your package.json to package from npm repository.
2. So as you upgraded node version, you need to rebuild native extensions. The easiest way to do this, is to remove node_modules folder, clean npm cache and install dependencies from the scratch: `rm -rf node_modules && npm cache verify && npm i`

Answer (score 0):

You can run the node setup again with repair mode fixed my problem.